# Replicating a button and edit text by clicking a previously replicated button, ANDROID

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-edittext

I have a specific issue with my code which most trade I have visited have been unable to solve.

From my app, I will like to create a situation where a user can create a new class by clicking a "add new class" button, when this is done, an edittext and another button is created, the user can as well click on the newly created button to add new class which as well creates a new edit text field and another button should the user wish to keep adding new classes. The challanges here are

Right now when a user clicks on the "add new class" button, multiple buttons as the same number of the array in the code is generated which is not what I want to achieve. Thank you

I am quit New to Android development and the entire Java programming language

My SchoolSearch setup class here

```
package com.example.demeainc.demea;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SchoolSearchSetup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText searchSchoolID;
    private Button searchSchoolButtonID;
    private ListView listOfSchoolsID;
    private Button  openNewschoolID;
    private LinearLayout schoolSetupLayout;
    private Button addNewClass;
    private EditText classNameEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_search_setup);
        findAllViewsID();
        initializeListenners();
    }

    public void findAllViewsID(){

        classNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.classNameText);
        addNewClass = findViewById(R.id.addNewClassButton);
        schoolSetupLayout = findViewById(R.id.schoolSetupLayout);
        searchSchoolID = findViewById(R.id.searchSchoolID);
        searchSchoolButtonID = findViewById(R.id.searchSchoolButtonID);
        listOfSchoolsID = findViewById(R.id.listOfSchoolsID);
        openNewschoolID = findViewById(R.id.openNewschoolID);


    }

    public void initializeListenners(){
        openNewschoolID.setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);
        addNewClass.setOnClickListener(SchoolSearchSetup.this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.openNewschoolID:

               displaySchoolSetUpForms();

               break;

           case R.id.addNewClassButton:

               addNewClassSetUp();


        }

    }


    private void addNewClassSetUp() {

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        layout.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        schoolSetupLayout.addView(layout);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        EditText addClassEditTex = new EditText(this);

        addClassEditTex.setHint("Class name, e.g Grade one");

        addClassEditTex.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        schoolSetupLayout.addView(addClassEditTex);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams addNewClassButtonParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 60);

        String[] arrayClass = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
                "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45",
                "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60"};

        int length = arrayClass.length;

        Button[] addNewClassBtn = new Button[length];


        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){


         addNewClassBtn[i] = new Button(this);


        addNewClassBtn[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        addNewClassBtn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

        addNewClassBtn[i].setText("Add New Class");

        addNewClassBtn[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        addNewClassBtn[i].setLayoutParams(addNewClassButtonParams);

        schoolSetupLayout.addView(addNewClassBtn[i]);

            addNewClassBtn[i].setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(addNewClassBtn[i]));



    }

        String schoolSetupContent = String.valueOf(schoolSetupLayout);

        if (!schoolSetupContent.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "New class field created scroll down to view", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Class creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }

    View.OnClickListener handleOnClick(final Button button) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //dont get what else to do here

            }
        };
    }

    private void displaySchoolSetUpForms() {

        schoolSetupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not know the id's of view but, you can set tag when  component is created and search that component by `findViewWithTag`

like:

```
  Button btn = (Button)findViewWithTag("btn_send");
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer with regards to the IDs i will check this out. But meanwhile my main issue is......" I will like to create a situation where a user can create a new class by clicking a "add new class" button, when this is done, an edittext and another button is created, the user can as well click on the newly created button to add new class which as well creates a new edit text field and another button should the user wish to keep adding new classes".. I just edited the question to center on just this piece. Meanwhile your answer is quit helpful